# Parsing the large files in Perl

Tags: perl, file

I need to compare the big file(2GB) contains 22 million lines with the another file. its taking more time to process it while using Tie::File.so i have done it through 'while' but problem remains. see my code below...

```
use strict;
use Tie::File;
# use warnings;
my @arr;
# tie @arr, 'Tie::File', 'title_Nov19.txt';

# open(IT,"<title_Nov19.txt");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
# my @arr=<IT>;
# close(IT);
open(RE,">>res.txt");

open(IN,"<input.txt");

while(my $data=<IN>){
    chomp($data);
    print"$data\n";
    my $occ=0;

    open(IT,"<title_Nov19.txt");    
    while(my $line2=<IT>){

        my $line=$line2;
        chomp($line);

        if($line=~m/\b$data\b/is){

            $occ++;

        }

    }
print RE"$data\t$occ\n";
}


close(IT);
close(IN);
close(RE);
```

so help me to reduce it...

Comment: So you have problem X (comparing big files), then you try to solve it with Y (Tie::File) and it needs "more time"? More than what? Then you solve it with Z (no Tie::File) and the problem remains? It still needs "more time"? More than what? What's the actual problem? I'm confused. :(

Comment: if you are on linux/unix maybe you can do this without perl: `diff file1 file2 > result.txt`, if you want side-by-side comparison you can do `sdiff file1 file2 > result.txt`, or alternatively `diff -y file1 file2 > result.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Lots of things wrong with this.

Asides from the usual (lack of `use strict`, `use warnings`, use of 2-argument `open()`, not checking `open()` result, use of global filehandles), the specific problem in your case is that you are opening/reading/closing the second file once for every single line of the first. This is going to be very slow.

I suggest you open the file `title_Nov19.txt` once, read all the lines into an array or hash or something, then close it; and then you can open the first file, `input.txt` and walk along that once, comparing to things in the array so you don't have to reopen that second file all the time.

Futher I suggest you read some basic articles on style/etc.. as your question is likely to gain more attention if it's actually written in vaguely modern standards.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate reply... "I suggest you open the file title_Nov19.txt once, read all the lines into an array or hash or something, then close it; and then you can open the first file, input.txt and walk along that once, comparing to things in the array so you don't have to reopen that second file all the time."     i already tried this, you can see that its commented on my code. still tat is a problem

Comment: +1 for suggestion of caching that file. Now let's hope it's not as big as "the big file". ;)

Comment: @Arun still what is a problem?

Comment: I will explain it. The file 'input' contains more than 2000 lines of names and the 'title_nov19' contains titles of 2 mln lines. i want to run each name on top of the title file to get the occurrence count. now its taking 7 sec for each name to get the count. it should be reduced. thank you....

Comment: Oh, so `title_Nov19.txt` is the big file and `input.txt` is relative small? I thought it was the other way round and I'm pretty sure @LeoNerd thought that, too. You shouldn't cache the contents of the big file in an array.

Comment: @Arun check out my example script in my answer.

Comment: BTW, Tie::File does not load the entire file into memory, and also will automatically cache reads.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to build a small example script with a better structure but I have to say, man, your problem description is really very unclear. It's important to **not** read the whole comparison file each time as @LeoNerd explained in his answer. Then I use a hash to keep track of the match count:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# cache all lines of the comparison file
open my $comp_file, '<', 'input.txt' or die "input.txt: $!\n";
chomp (my @comparison = <$comp_file>);
close $comp_file;

# prepare comparison
open my $input,  '<', 'title_Nov19.txt' or die "title_Nov19.txt: $!\n";
my %count = ();

# compare each line
while (my $title = <$input>) {
    chomp $title;

    # iterate comparison strings
    foreach my $comp (@comparison) {
        $count{$comp}++ if $title =~ /\b$comp\b/i;
    }
}

# done
close $input;

# output (sorted by count)
open my $output, '>>', 'res.txt' or die "res.txt: $!\n";
foreach my $comp (@comparison) {
    print $output "$comp\t$count{$comp}\n";
}
close $output;
```

Just to get you started... If someone wants to further work on this: these were my test files:

**title_Nov19.txt**

```
This is the foo title
Wow, we have bar too
Nothing special here but foo
OMG, the last title! And Foo again!
```

**input.txt**

```
foo
bar
```

And the result of the program was written to **res.txt**:

```
foo 3
bar 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using [memowe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184510/memowe)'s (thank you) data:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp qw/read_file write_file/;

my %count;
my $regex = join '|', map { chomp; $_ = "\Q$_\E" } read_file 'input.txt';

for ( read_file 'title_Nov19.txt' ) {
    my %seen;
    !$seen{ lc $1 }++ and $count{ lc $1 }++ while /\b($regex)\b/ig;
}

write_file 'res.txt', map "$_\t$count{$_}\n",
  sort { $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} } keys %count;
```

Numerically-sorted output to `res.txt`:

```
foo 3
bar 1
```

An alternation regex which quotes meta characters (`\Q$_\E`) is built and used, so only one pass against the large file's lines is needed.  The hash `%seen` is used to insure that the input words are only counted once per line.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

grep -i -c -w -f input.txt title_Nov19.txt > res.txt